# Me gustaria saber por qué al usar preventDefault() no se envia el formulario

Tags: javascript, html

Actualmente estoy haciendo un proyecto en el que al enviar un formulario mediante HTML, primero verifique ciertos parametros, para ello hago uso de PreventDefault() de la siguiente forma:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PROYECTO JS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="ejemplo2.php" id="form">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="nombre"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contraseña</td>
            <td><input type="password" id="contrasena"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" onClick="warnings()"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <div id="warnings"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="ejemplo1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
const nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
const contra = document.getElementById("contrasena");
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const warnings = document.getElementById("warnings");


form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
        
        if(nombre.nodeValue.trim == null){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    
})
```

Pero lo que sucede es que aun cuando no se cumpla el parametro null (o sea que no este vació el input) NO se envía el formulario.

Comment: haz un ```console.log(nombre.nodeValue.trim)``` y mira lo que obtienes, ademas no creo que la comparacion a **null** sea la mejor, deberias de compararalo tambien a ```" "```

Answer (score 3):

Siempre devolverá nulo ya que tu código presenta 2 errores:

1. `nombre.nodeValue.trim` siempre devuelve `null`. `nodeValue` devuelve el contenido del nodo, en el caso de un input, será `null`. Si quieres obtener el valor del input debes usar `nombre.value`.

```javascript
nombre.nodeValue // incorrecto, siempre devuelve null en un input
nombre.value // correcto, devolverá el valor en curso
```

2. Una vez que corrijas `nombre.value.trim`, se te generará otro error. Para utilizar el método `trim` debes invocarlo. `nombre.value.trim` devuelve el método, `nombre.value.trim()` ejecuta el método y devuelve el valor con el método aplicado.

```javascript
nombre.value.trim // devuelve el método para ser ejecutado, sin lanzarlo
nombre.value.trim() // dispara el método y lo aplica a nombre.value
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{

    const nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
    const contra = document.getElementById("contrasena");
    const secont = document.getElementById("secontrasena");
    const form = document.getElementById("form");

    form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){

        if(nombre.value == "" || contra.value == "" || contra.value != secont.value){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('No se puede');
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title>PROYECTO JS</title>
    <script src="js/027.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="ejemplo2.php" id="form">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="nombre"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contraseña</td>
            <td><input type="password" id="contrasena"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="password" id="secontrasena" placeholder="Repite la Contraseña"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Yo me tomé la libertad también de añadirte una regla más al preventDefault, que es comprobar que las contraseñas están correctas ambas dos, si no hay, o no son iguales, detiene el proceso.